# How to create an overlay that covers only a certain container, not a whole html page?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to create an overlay container or modal which covers only a certain container on a page. I have this.

```
#overlay {
    position: fixed;
    display: none;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    z-index: 2;
    cursor: pointer;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div id="overlay" onclick="off()"></div>

<div style="padding:20px; border: 3px solid black;" id="my_main_div">
  <h2>Overlay</h2>
  <p>Add an overlay effect to the page content (100% width and height with a black background color with 50% opacity).</p>
  <button onclick="on()">Turn on overlay effect</button>
</div>

<script>
function on() {
    document.getElementById("overlay").style.display = "block";
}

function off() {
    document.getElementById("overlay").style.display = "none";
}
</script>
```

But this overlay covers all the page. Whereas I want it to cover **only** `my_main_div` and nothing else. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this you need to do -

```
//html

<div style="padding:20px; border: 3px solid black;" id="my_main_div">
    <div id="overlay" onclick="off()"></div>
    <h2>Overlay</h2>
    <p>Add an overlay effect to the page content (100% width and height with a black background color with 50% opacity).</p>
    <button onclick="on()">Turn on overlay effect</button>
</div>

//css

#my_main_div {
  position: relative;
}

#overlay {
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    z-index: 2;
    cursor: pointer;
}

// js

function on() {
    document.getElementById("overlay").style.display = "block";
}

function off() {
    document.getElementById("overlay").style.display = "none";
}
```

Comment: no css styles should be applied to `my_main_div`. it's shouldn't be touched.

Comment: can you please tell the reason why css shouldn't be applied to `my_main_div`

Answer (score 0):

use relative as Position.

```js
function on() {
    document.getElementById("overlay").style.display = "block";
}

function off() {
    document.getElementById("overlay").style.display = "none";
}
```

```css
.row {
  position: relative;
}
#overlay {
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    z-index: 2;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
<div id="overlay" onclick="off()"></div>

<div style="padding:20px; border: 3px solid black;" id="my_main_div">
  <h2>Overlay</h2>
  <p>Add an overlay effect to the page content (100% width and height with a black background color with 50% opacity).</p>
  <button onclick="on()">Turn on overlay effect</button>
</div>
</div>
```